# Tableau JSON request not working

Tags: jquery, tableau-api

I am a complete Tableau newbie working on the tutorial. I've made a getJSON() request and my script hangs and never returns. What am I doing wrong? I've tested the link in my browser and a response is returned almost immediately, so it's not a speed problem.

```
(function () {
var myConnector = tableau.makeConnector();

myConnector.getSchema = function (schemaCallback) {
    var cols = [
        {id: "mag", alias: "magnitude", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float},
        {id: "title", alias: "title", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string},
        {id: "url", alias: "url", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.string},
        {id: "lat", alias: "latitude", columnRole: "dimension", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float},
        {id: "lon", alias: "longitude", columnRole: "dimension", dataType: tableau.dataTypeEnum.float}
    ];

    var tableInfo = {
        id: "earthquakeFeed",
        alias: "Significant Earthquakes in the last seven days",
        columns: cols
    };

    schemaCallback([tableInfo]);
    //tableau.log("Hello WDC!");
};

myConnector.getData = function (table, doneCallback) {
    $.getJSON("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.geojson", function (resp) {
        var feat = resp.features,
                tableData = [];

        // Iterate over the JSON object
        for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
            tableData.push({
                "id": feat[i].id,
                "mag": feat[i].properties.mag,
                "title": feat[i].properties.title,
                "lon": feat[i].geometry.coordinates[0],
                "lat": feat[i].geometry.coordinates[1]
            });
        }

        table.appendRows(tableData);
        doneCallback();
    });
};


tableau.registerConnector(myConnector);
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submitButton").click(function () {
        tableau.connectionName = "Stock Data for ";
        tableau.connectionData = "tickerSymbol";
        tableau.submit();
    });
});})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a true newb; I had a CORS problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The output of `npm start` mentions something about a proxy server but isn't very helpful. The CORS issue should be front and center in the tutorial rather than a footnote you have to dig up.
The solution is to prepend localhost:8889 to your jQuery `$.getJSON()` request.

So this:

`"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.geojson"`

Becomes this:
`"http://localhost:8889/earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_week.geojson"`